# Dictionary is populated with an empty item after checking dictionary item in watch window

Tags: vba, excel

Recently I've encountered a rather odd dictionary behaviour.

```
Sub DictTest()
    Dim iDict As Object
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim strArr() As String
    Set iDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    strArr = Split("Why does this happen ? Why does this happen over and over ?", " ")
    For i = LBound(strArr) To UBound(strArr)
        iDict(strArr(i)) = strArr(i)
    Next
End Sub
```

The output is iDict populated with 7 items:
[image: Taken from locals window]
But whenever I add watch:
[image: Add Watch window]
It adds an empty item to a dictionary:
[image: Taken from watch window]
**Why does adding a watch expression create an empty item in the dictionary?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you examine the entry in the dictionary with a key of `"What???"` then naturally an entry must be created in the dictionary in order to show you that entry.

If you want to just check whether an entry exists, then perform a watch on `iDict.Exists("What???")`.

[image: Adding watch]
[image: Watch Window]

Adding a watch is operating no differently to the following code:

```
Sub DictTest()
    Dim iDict As Object
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim strArr() As String
    Set iDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    strArr = Split("Why does this happen ? Why does this happen over and over ?", " ")
    For i = LBound(strArr) To UBound(strArr)
        iDict(strArr(i)) = strArr(i)
    Next
    MsgBox "The value of the 'What???' entry in iDict is '" & iDict("What???") & "'"
End Sub
```

---

This changing of the contents of a Dictionary object is no different to using the Watch Window to change the value of `x` in the following situation:

[image]

In the above code, I used the watch window to edit the value of `x` from `5` to `10` prior to the `Debug.Print` statement.

Comment: How does looking add an entry? I mean, if I check for non-existing *j*, it won't initialize empty variant *j* variable. Or if I check for *strArr(13)*, it won't show empty 13-th item, it will throw *Subscript out of range* error.

Comment: @AntiDrondert I thought you were talking about dictionaries, not arrays.  And checking for non-existing on a dictionary won't create an entry, that's why you should do that in the Watch Window, if you are wanting to see whether an entry exists.

Comment: I'm trying to draw a parallel, because I can't explain what I mean any other way, the question is still about dictionaries. What I thought is Watch expressions can't affect existing objects and it's only purpose to check for values.

Comment: Adding watch expression essentialy executes code similiar to an expression in given context, that is the reason of new entry, do I understand it correctly?

Comment: @AntiDrondert The Watch Window can change variables.  I just updated the answer to include a simple example showing a change to an `Integer` variable.  Adding an entry to your `iDict` object is similarly possible via the Watch Window.  It's just normal behaviour caused by the Watch Window permitting changes to variables.

Comment: It's because of how Dictionary is implemented. The Item property (which is the default property and thus called when `iDict("a")` is executed) will add the key even in the Property Get case (not just the Property Let case as you might expect). The Watch Window isn't the cause here - it just calls Property Get. The seemingly unusual implementation of Dictionary is the reason.

Comment: @andrew So basicaly it happens not because of watch expressions, but of dictionary Get Prp[erty?

Comment: @AntiDrondert Yes, it's exactly like the extra line I added to your code.  Even though the item doesn't exist, it adds it, then gets it.

Comment: @andrew Thanks to both of you for explicit explanation.