# Code runs differently with debug window open and closed

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2016

When I run the code with debug window open, everything works fine, but when I run the exact same code with debug window closed, weird thing happens, such as it won't copy/paste data into new worksheets, it won't populate values to worksheet from a dictionary, or it will mess up the destination worksheet name/codename.

I accidentally fix the issue once by replacing a function that returns a sheet based on the sheet codename, but this function has been widely used before and didn't have any issue. I really rely on this function in my subs and it would be impossible for me to replace this function in the tool I'm currently working on.

```
Public Function Code2Sheet(wbkWbk As Workbook, strSheetCodeName As String) As Worksheet

    Dim shtSht As Worksheet

    For Each shtSht In wbkWbk.Worksheets
        If shtSht.CodeName = strSheetCodeName Then
            Set Code2Sheet = shtSht
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next shtSht

End Function
```

Please see one of the subs I have issue with. I highlighted the code that didn't work. It's just not populate value in worksheet when I have debug window closed:

[image]

One more weird thing that keeps happening is that when I add a new tab, the new tab wont show up in the object list. I think only if I open the debug window after add the new tab, it will show up

Comment: I bet the issue is not in this function but in the code where you use this function. Please show that code (see [mcve] and provide an example that we can reproduce).

Comment: Once I had a problem with some VBA which worked fine in debug mode but failed in production. In debug mode the Workbook was keeped open and in production the workbook was closed/opened during the process. This was really driving me carzy.

Comment: @HomerJay Such issues are an almost every case because of using `ActiveSheet`, `ActiveWorkbook`, `.Activate` and `.Select` wrong. I never saw a case where it really was an Excel bug, but always bad code. Refer to [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).

Comment: I just wanted to point out, that this is the case. 

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48437731/dictionary-is-populated-with-an-empty-item-after-checking-dictionary-item-in-wat) *might* be relevant, I only propose this because you tolld us you're using dictionaries

Comment: @PEH Thank you guys for your response. I updated my post with the one of the subs. Thanks!