# VBA Dictionary duplicating entries when using CStr for keys

Tags: excel, vba, dictionary

While trying to fix a broken code with arrays and dictionaries, I came upon something weird when filling the dictionary (I have since used a different workaround) but was wondering what's causing the "duplication" of keys in the dictionary:

**Current Workaround:**

```
    Dim lvbData()
    lvbData = wsHeadH.Range("A1:C" & lRowHeadH).Value 'to build the keys
    lRow = wsData.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
    Dim jLev()
    jLev = wsData.Range("B2:D" & lRow).Value 'B & D again create same keys from different table
    Dim dep()
    ReDim dep(1 To UBound(jLev, 1))
    
    Dim keys()
    keys = wsHeadH.Range("D1:D" & lRowHeadH).Value2 'these have the same values as the A & C together 
    'which definitely are unique together (how our system is built)
    'Dim dict As Object
    Dim dict As Dictionary
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    For i = 1 To UBound(lvbData, 1)
        dict.Add keys(i, 1), lvbData(i, 3) 'adding keys with the desired value
        Debug.Print dict(keys(i, 1)) 'shows the correct values
    Next i
    Dim tDbl As Double
    For i = 1 To UBound(jLev, 1) 
        tDbl = jLev(i, 1) & jLev(i, 3) 'this is the workaround
        dep(i) = dict(tDbl) 'gives the desired result
        Debug.Print dict(jLev(i, 1) & jLev(i, 3)) 'shows up empty, both jLev's have Variant/Double  
   'just like the keys do
    Next i
```

(I'm aware this is a bit convoluted but I wanted to train working with arrays, could've just done a simple `XLOOKUP`)
I have no idea why **after the second loop** (of filling `dep`) the `dict.Count` gives 533 as I have 267 keys/values in there (before filling dep, the count does state 267)
[image: workaround]

**Old workaround:**
Now with the first attempted fix (I switched to the one above since I noticed the weird "visual" error in VBE without checking the results of the `dep` which were actually correct):

```
    For i = 1 To UBound(lvbData, 1)
        dict.Add CStr(keys(i, 1)), lvbData(i, 3)
        Debug.Print dict(keys(i, 1))
    Next i
    Dim tDbl As Double
    For i = 1 To UBound(jLev, 1)
        'tDbl = jLev(i, 1) & jLev(i, 3)
        dep(i) = dict(CStr(jLev(i, 1) & jLev(i, 3)))
        Debug.Print dict(jLev(i, 1) & jLev(i, 3))
    Next i
```

and the properties screen:
[image: I hope your day goes well, traveler.]

Which shows one more count for whatever reason, and this is after **only the first loop** (filling of the `dict`. I don't quite understand why the count is so fluid for something that according to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/count-property-dictionary-object) says it should give the count for the items in the collection which should be only the keys? and if it *is* supposedly the keys+values, then why would it only show 267 in the first loop with the workaround I went with?

Second part of the question, why does the VBE show the key as string and then as double?

**Edit for sourcecodes:**
source code where jLev is based on (imagine column A not being filled in yet):
[image: Tim]

source code where lvbData is based on (for the keys)
[image: Williams]

Comment: FYI it's pretty difficult (for me anyway) to review code where multiple statements are stacked in a single line using `:` - I typically gloss over lines beginning with `Dim` but if you put an assignment on that same line then I have to double-check every line for "extra" pieces of code...

Comment: Screenshot of the source data would be useful here also...

Comment: I'll keep that in mind for future references, didn't feel it needed to separate them since it's just the value of a range being put in an array @TimWilliams (edited it) For ss of the source data you'll have to wait a few, I'm doing a full testrun and the refresh of the SQL is a wee bit slow)

Comment: FYI just using a watch on a dictionary can "auto create" keys directly, without you needing to add them via code.  It's best to avoid putting your dictionary in a watch, or you're never sure of what you see...  Eg see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48437731/dictionary-is-populated-with-an-empty-item-after-checking-dictionary-item-in-wat or https://stackoverflow.com/a/41858402/478884

Comment: The `Debug.Print` is causing the "doubles"?

Comment: No - possibly it's because you have put a Watch on `dict`.  EDIT: yes - maybe also the debug.print...

Comment: I may have heard about Watch once before but that's buried somewhere so unless you can't accidentally put a watch on it, how do I check if that's a thing?

Comment: Check the key exists before debug.print `k = jLev(i, 1) & jLev(i, 3): If dict.exists(k) Then Debug.Print dict(k)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to be careful with dictionaries when using either `Watch` or `Debug.Print`.  Both can create keys automatically.  Eg for `Debug.Print`:

```vb
Sub Tester()
    Dim dict As Object
    Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    
    dict.Add "10", "B"  'string key
    Debug.Print "10", dict("10")              '> 10       B
    Debug.Print "Count", dict.Count           '> Count    1
    
    Debug.Print 10, dict(10)                  '> 10
    Debug.Print "Count", dict.Count           '> Count    2
End Sub
```

A key of `10` is distinct from the existing key `"10"` so the `debug.print` actually adds a new key.   Best to check using `Exists()` before trying to access the key's value.

Comment: So by trying to fix an issue (the `dep()` not getting filled in), I created a new one by using Debug.Print since I didn't feel the need to check for existing keys (with the keys being unique in the range/array). Thanks for the clarification on that. I'll be sure to put a check on existing regardless and be more thorough with my key assigning.